# Typhoon: Exception when retrieving storyboard from assembly

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, typhoon

I am using Typhoon for dependency injection. But I have a problem. Occasionally, I get the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No component matching id 'nemIdStoryboard'.'
```

The code, where this exception occurs, looks like this:

```
class PaymentApproveViewController : UIViewController {
   var assembly : ApplicationAssembly!
   //...
   private func signPayment() {
      let storyboard = assembly.nemIdStoryboard()
      let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as NemIDViewController
   //...
   }
}
```

And my assembly code looks like this:

```
public dynamic func rootViewController() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(RootViewController.self) {
        $0.injectProperty("assembly", with: self)
    }
}

public dynamic func paymentApproveViewController() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(PaymentApproveViewController.self) {
        $0.injectProperty("assembly", with: self)
    }
}
public dynamic func nemIdStoryboard() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(TyphoonStoryboard.self) {
        $0.useInitializer("storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:") {
            $0.injectParameterWith("NemID")
            $0.injectParameterWith(TyphoonBlockComponentFactory(assembly:self))
            $0.injectParameterWith(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I have the exact same code for injecting the assembly into my RootViewController, which also retrieves a storyboard and instantiates a view controller the same way as above. But this never fails.

I cannot identify any reason to why this should fail occasionally, and not be consistent. But I have a feeling, that the assembly might not be properly initialized in Swift code using optional types. Could that be the case? Or can you suggest anything I can do to make this code work?

**Edit:**

I have printed out `TyphoonComponentFactory._registry` from rootViewController and from PaymentApproveViewController. The interesting result is that:

- In RootViewController, the `_registry` contains a list of *all* typhoon definitions in my ApplicationAssembly. That is, all objects and storyboard definitions
- In PaymentApproveViewController, the `_registry` contains all objects *except* my five storyboards. This is the reason that TyphoonComponentFactory.componentForKey throws an exception when it does not find the storyboard.

BTW: The address of the assembly is different in `rootViewController` and `PaymentApproveViewController`. So it is two different assemblies that are injected. Can this be avoided, or is it expected behavior?

Comment: Can you NSLog the assembly from the root view controller and the one in the payment controller. It should list the definitions that are registered. Maybe also include `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", assembly) to get the address of the assembly (check they're the same one). . . how are you instantiating Typhoon? Using plist integration? . . . about your theory, I don't think its plausible, there's probably another reason. . we can discuss.

Comment: @JasperBlues: I was actually working on it already. I think the findings in my edit above answers your questions. I am instantiating Typhoon using plist integration.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is unexpected behavior. Can you show me how RootViewController is obtaining the assembly and how PaymentViewController is? Let's work out why they are different.

Comment: @JasperBlues: I am not sure what you mean by "obtaining". I have added my typhoon definition of RootViewController to the sample code. Is that what you requested? As you can see, the code is exactly the same as the other controller. Of course, I have shortened the definition of `paymentApproveViewController()`, which actually have two injected properties (the other property is an array). But I am not expecting that to affect this problem, therefore I deleted that from the sample code above

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, I think I have a solution for you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with:

```
$0.injectParameterWith(TyphoonBlockComponentFactory(assembly:self))
```

This is instantiating a new assembly using only the definitions found in the current one, and skipping any collaborating assemblies. You actually want:

```
$0.injectParameterWith(self)
```

In Objective-C its possible to cast any `TyphoonAssembly` to `TyphoonComponentFactory` (at runtime your assemblies are just an instance of `TyphoonComponentFactory` posing as an assembly in any case). With Swift's strict type checking this isn't possible, so instead **[Typhoon 3.0](http://cocoapods.org/?q=typhoon)** has the `TyphoonAssembly` class conforms to the `TyphoonComponentFactory` protocol, so if you need any methods from this interface they are available. Eg:

```
assembly.componentForType(SomeType.self)
```

**Summary**

- In Swift we only inject `TyphoonAssembly` not `TyphoonComponentFactory`.
- `TyphoonAssembly` conforms to the `TyphoonComponentFactory` protocol.

Comment: Since what you tried is not supported, perhaps we can add some checking to raise an error for this case.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I didn't realize that I should inject `self` directly like that when I set things up in the beginning, since I apparently missed that the TyphoonAssembly conformed to TyphoonComponentFactory. And since everything (almost) worked, I had no idea that it was done wrong. So it would be a good idea to raise an error in this case. Thank you very much for your help!